# How can I get the structure of the variational ansatz for VQLS?

Tags: architecture, variational-quantum-algorithms

I have got a system of linear equations
$$
A|x \rangle = |b\rangle \\
A = 0.45Z_3 + 0.55I \\
|b\rangle = H_1 H_2 H_3
$$
and I would like to solve it for $|x\rangle$.
[image: Qiskit variational circuit architecture]
I am currently trying to understand the architecture of the variational ansatz in the [qiskit tutorial](https://github.com/Qiskit/textbook/blob/main/notebooks/ch-applications/vqls.ipynb). I understood the set of three Hadamard gates, which comes from $U = H_1 H_2 H_3$, and the implemented Hadamard test which causes the need for the first auxiliary qubit $q1_0$.
[image: Hadamard test overview]
I would also understand the rotational gates, but why there is a need for the second auxiliary qubit $g1_4$? I have seen some other architectures of the variational ansatz, but there are only entanglement gates between the qubits and there is no need for an extra qubit.

[image: Typical architecture of the variational circuit]

**How can I scale this circuit for 5 or 6 qubits?**

Thank you for your response.